# JavaScript Assigning innerHTML a button, however does not click

Tags: javascript, html, button

when I assign the

```
// psuedo code
.innerHTML = [ a button here ]; // see exact code below
```

it does nothing when clicked. Is there an alternative to doing this? or is it not possible?

the table is dynamically created by JavaScript. As each cell is populated, a criterion is checked - and if met, will produce a button in the following cell. this works and does as intended, however, the button does nothing when clicked. 
When checking the source, the button does not show, even though it is there on the HTML page.

I tried elements, that did not work, and I think it is because it is handled outside of the table, where this code is internal.

```
// the culprit line
cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML =  '<button class="calc" onclick="calculateGrade();"> + </button>';
```

Not sure if I need to post more code, but this line should show what I am attempting to do.

the button has to be done dynamically since it checks each row.

For educational purposes:

1. why is the button not able to respond?
2. is there a way to make this work as is?
3. is there another option to achieve the same results?

edit ----------------------------------
Just a snippit of the function it calls. code ommited as it never gets there

```
function calculateGrade() {
    console.log('here'); // <--- THIS NEVER SHOWS UP, BUTTON IS NOT SENDING IT HERE
        // code cleared for clarity
    }
```

## EDIT 2

```
for(let i=0; i < studentList.length-1; i++) {

        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML = studentList[i];
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML = grade      
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML = maxGrade;
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML = student.name;  

        if(student.grade < maxGrade) { // change later to within 90%
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML =  '<button  onclick="calculateGrade();" > + </button>';
            }else{
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);  cell.innerHTML = 'Pass';
        }

}
```

Comment: Making sure: have you ensured that `calculateGrade` is or is not being called with say, a `console.log` statement in that function?

Comment: yes ```console.log('here i am');``` doesn't get there :-) (I do that in lots of my code for a check point)

Comment: The current code looks fine. Add more code which can help reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you have access to the script which generates the table cells and puts the button there ?

Comment: posted Edit 2. Edit 1 has the function, but the code never gets to the console log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**manipulation the dom**

if you want to manipulate the dom "a hundrets of time" you should use a framework like jQuery or the javascript own functions for dom manipulation instead of innerHTML.
Why?
HTML has changed from time to time and you can't know, if your innerHTML will be correct (formatted) in the future.
`document.createElement`as example will work in every browser.

Also there is the possibility, that dom manipulation functions will be more optimized by compilers and engines in future.

**Dynamic listeners**

If you create dom elements dynamicly you don't have to declare the listeners as text.

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.addEventListener('onclick', calculateGrade);
cell.appendChild(button);
```

also this is less vulnerable for typos ;)

**dynamic element creation and reflow**

Whenever you change something in the dom that is a visible change, the browser fill fire a reflow. It will recalculate all elements sizes. As you can imagine, adding "a hundrets" of buttons will cause a hundrets of reflows.

Reflow will not trigger on invisible objects. so best practise if you manipulate a lot of elements is to turn the parent invisible, then make your changes and make the parent visible again. In this case you trigger a reflow only twice.

Comment: You are correct, and in the past that is how I did it, But that was for small 5 - 10 row tables, however, manually creating a table (via HTML) could be redundant. So I did a loop in JS to create the table, and only checking certain values to "create" the button. Or do you suggest keep making the table via HTML, hiding the buttons, and calling the visible when needed? (I slightly exaggerated, its more like 20 - 30 rows, some classes are a little larger but not by much)

Comment: If you add the cells BEFORE you append it to the dom, you will trigger a reflow only once (best practise). But if your table is still attached to the dom (e.g. body) you should hide (css: display: none) it before you manipulate it (adding rows, cells, buttons, ...). After you finished your manipulation, make it visible again (css: display: initial). So you trigger the reflow only on making it invisible and on making it visible again (=twice) instead of triggering anreflow on very manipulation. Also check <https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow>

Comment: Im marking yours as best (everyone had some good answers) but yours made me realize I was getting a reflow issue (turned on console and saw it) then went back and reread your answer. changed the code a little bit. Seems to be working. It seems to have been a dom issue and order - as you said. That is where to lock up started as well. I've since redid some of the code - thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function myFunction() {
       var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
  var x = row.insertCell(-1);
      x.innerHTML =  '<button class="calc" onclick="calculateGrade();"> +button </button>';
    }


    function calculateGrade() {
      alert("Hi am working action");
    }
```

```html
Check here the new add button is working when I am adding cell.innerHTML there will calc button and when you will click it will show "Hi am working action,"  I think it will help you 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the table row.</p>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td>Second cell</td>
        <td>Third cell</td>
      </tr>
       <tr id="myRow">
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td>Second cell</td>
        <td>Third cell</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td>Second cell</td>
        <td>Third cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table><br>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you read my post, the table is built DYNAMICALLY not via HTML. I have hudreds of data, that I will not manually put into HTML. You example works fine, but not for me ```The table is dynamically created by JavaScript. As each cell is populated, a criteria is checked - and if met, will produce a button in the following cell.```

Comment: if you add a DYNAMICALLY  table reach cell is okay you can set also use condition for button displaying and it will work there also I think.   can you send me your table generating function?

Comment: hmmm I see how yours can work. Your doing a static assignment. what if there are 3 cells in the table that come up.  the my function would calculate all of them at once. Might be useful. Not quite there though. But I will tinker with that code. interesting concept

Answer (score 0):

Do not use onevent attributes:

`<button` <del>onclick="func()"</del>`>...</button>`

Use either onevent property:

`document.querySelector('button').onclick = function;`

Or an eventListener:

`document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function)`

Use **[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)** -- a programming pattern that allows us to register ***a single event handler*** to listen for an ***unlimited number of elements***. Here's a simplified outline:

1. Choose an element that is a common ancestor to all of the elements we want to react to an event. This includes `window` and `document` as well, but `window` should be used for key events (ex. `document.onclick = calculateGrade`)
2. The callback function (ex. `calculateGrade(e)`) must pass the Event Object (`event`, `evt`, or `e` are the most common names).
3. Reference the clicked, changed, hovered, etc. element with the event property `Event.target` (ex. `const tgt = e.target`).
4. Isolate `Event.target` by `if...else` control statements (ex. `if (tgt.matches('button')) {...`)

The rest of the code is just to dynamically generate a table for demonstration purposes. Although the code that generates a table in OP question is dubious it wasn't part of the question so there's no explanation for that part in the demo.

```js
const tData = [{
  name: 'zer00ne',
  grade: 100
}, {
  name: 'Trump',
  grade: 25
}, {
  name: 'Joe Average',
  grade: 75
}, {
  name: 'Slacker',
  grade: 50
}];
const tHdrs = [`<th>#</th>`, `<th>Name</th>`, `<th>Grade</th>`, `<th>&nbsp;</th>`];
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
const table = document.createElement('table');
frag.appendChild(table);
const title = table.createCaption();
title.textContent = 'Student Grades';
const head = table.createTHead();
const hRow = head.insertRow(-1);
let h = tHdrs.length - 1;
for (let th of tHdrs) {
  th = hRow.insertCell(0).outerHTML = tHdrs[h];
  --h;
}
let rowQty = tData.length;
let colQty = tHdrs.length;
const body = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(body);
for (let r = 0; r < rowQty; r++) {
  let row = body.insertRow(-1);
  for (let c = 0; c < colQty; c++) {
    let col = c => row.insertCell(c);
    let cell = col(c);
    if (c === 0) {
      cell.textContent = r + 1;
    } else if (c === colQty - 1) {
      if (tData[r].grade > 69) {
        cell.textContent = 'Pass';
      } else {
        cell.innerHTML = `<button>Calculate</button>`;
      }
    } else if (c === 1) {
      cell.textContent = tData[r].name;
    } else {
      cell.textContent = tData[r].grade;
    }
  }
}
const foot = table.createTFoot();
const fRow = foot.insertRow(-1);
const fCol = fRow.insertCell(0);
fCol.textContent = 'Passing grade is 70% or more.'
fCol.setAttribute('colspan', '4');
fCol.className = 'note';

document.body.appendChild(frag);

// Relevant Code
document.onclick = calculateGrade;

function calculateGrade(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('button')) {
    let row = tgt.closest('tr');
    let grd = row.children[2].textContent;
    let num = parseFloat(grd);
    console.log(num);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 5vh/1 Verdana;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 96%;
}

caption {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

th,
td {
  border: 2px ridge #000;
  min-height: 30px;
}

th:first-of-type {
  width: 10%;
}

th:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 20%;
}

th:last-of-type {
  width: 25%
}

td:first-of-type,
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

td:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content: '%';
}

td:first-of-type.note {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: none
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  width: 100%
}
```